# Is it possible to build a cumulative formula that will sum on new worksheet added daily?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, vba

I have a worksheet that the user opens each day and clicks a button that copies the current sheet to a new sheet and renames (Day 1, Day 2, etc.).

I want to keep a cumulative count in some of the cells on those sheets. For example, on Day one there was 1 safety incident entered into the sheet in the Daily column and the Cumulative column calculates 1. When the Day 2 sheet is created, I want the Cumulative column to add Day 1's incident to any incident number entered into Day 2 Daily cell. Then when the Day 3 sheet is created, I want it to sum any incidents from all 3 days in the Cumulative cell.

There could be any number of Days to a project and I want the most recent day to always have the correct cumulative number of incidents. Other worksheets in the workbook will also need to pull information from the most current sheet as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you are naming your sheets as stated in your question and the new sheet is active. You will add this code to the end of your existing code. It will create a formula to calculate the cumulative value you seek. When the user enters or changes a value in the number of incidents, it will update.

```
Dim intLast
Dim strSheet As String

'Get name of active sheet
strSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    If strSheet <> "Day 1" Then 'Skips the Day 1 sheet

        intLast = Right(strSheet, 1) - 1
        strSheet = "Day " & intLast

        'Add formula to sum total from the previous day and this sheet
        Range("C1").Formula = "=A1+'" & strSheet & "'!C1"

    End If

intLast = ""
strSheet = ""
```

Change the code so the cell address 'C1' is the address where you want the cumulative total. Also, change `A1` to the cell which has the user input value of safety incidents.